# NullPointerException in ClientTest

Tags: java, spring, junit

When trying to test Java Client's methods I'm receiving a NPE on the RepoService saveAndFlush method.

```
public class ClientTest{

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private ClientX client;

    @InjectMocks
    serviceX service;

    @Mock
    repoX repo;
```

Then having the test where I expect to get an exception

```
@Test (expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() {
        when(ClientX.blabla()).thenThrow(new Exception("400"));
        when(clientConfig.getServiceName()).thenReturn("");

        ClientX.isStatusActive(id);
    }
```

Test then fails with a NPE on this line from ClientX

```
 serviceX.saveError(new Error("BLABLA", e.getMessage()));
```

Anyone has an idea why serviceX or repoX is null/getting NPE?

Comment: Are you trying to mock calls to a static method ClientX.blabal() here? In any case, please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingl.y

Answer (score 0):

Try to add *@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)* at the top of the class otherwise Mockito will fail to create the context and the mocked beans

Comment: Fixed it by using @Mock on the service. Thanks though :)